# Is it possible to build UI elements from a database table using the Netbeans GUI designer?

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans

I'm building an application with a form that I'd like to populate with questions from a database table.

Is it possible to do this in the Netbeans GUI designer so that each question is inserted into the label of a checkbox element?

My initial idea of how to do this would be to get a result set back from the database and loop it, however I'm new to the Netbeans environment and tying this in with the GUI designer is escaping me....

Comment: Yes it is very well possible, try creating simple JDBC programs

Comment: @org.life.java - could you give me some pointers on where to start? I've already got a GUI and DB connection running, however I'm completely stuck getting the GUI designer to loop a table before it creates x number of elements!

Comment: don;t stay dependent on designer , write code instead for this functionality, use designer just to design the view and ..things

Comment: however I'm completely stuck getting the GUI designer to loop a table before it creates x number of elements! You can fetch all the data from DB before creating UI .then create a loop that will add GUI components to your UI depending on the list content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans learning trail contains one tutorial explaining the Beans Binding and creating Database application through wizard.

The tutorial is located at http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db.html

You can create a template application using this tutorial and then use the concepts and code provided in the wizard generated application in your application to do the binding of the elements with the data from database.

with regards
Tushar Joshi, Nagpur